# How do I return a console command as a String to a running software?

Tags: linux, shell, grails, groovy, terminal

Let me give a simple example:
In a Linux environment I have a Grails script, and I want to get all my directories using **ls** command:

```
def ls = "ls".execute()
println ls
// result is java.lang.UNIXProcess@f16b42
```

Instead of getting the process ID, I want to get the same output I get into a terminal

Ps.: This is just a example, I don't really need to list directories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quick way is:

```
String output = 'ls'.execute().text
println output
```

HOWEVER! If it writes a lot of output, the reader will fill up, and then it will all block.  So, you need to do something like:

```
String output = new StringWriter().with { out ->
    Process proc = 'ls'.execute()
    proc.consumeProcessOutput( out, System.err )
    proc.waitFor()
    out.toString()
}
println output
```

Of course, you might want to check the exitCode that `proc.waitFor()` returns, and do something better with the error stream then send it to `System.err`, but you get the idea ;-)

Comment: Thank you! I'm still new to Groovy, things like closures are strange to me, but it answered my question.

Comment: Also note that execute() will NOT work on built-in commands (like "dir" in windows), only executables.  For this to work on built-in commands you need to execute a shell and then send the "dir" text to the shell or pass it as a /C parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like this.

```
File directory = new File(args[0])
Process p = "ls".execute([], directory)            
p.waitForProcessOutput(System.out, System.err)
```

If this were a script called listFiles.groovy, you could run

```
groovy listFiles ~/blah
```

and see everything in the blah directory. This is going to wait for the process to finish before moving onto any other commands.

Check out the groovy docs for [Process](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Process.html). There is a lot of fun stuff there.